# month starting another day

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been using `MONTH()` function to get the months and grouping by month, like this example query.

```
SELECT 
    t1.ano,
    t1.mes,
    tempo_extra,
    tempo_ativo,
    tempo_extra / tempo_ativo AS volume_extra
FROM
    (SELECT 
        YEAR(`data`) AS ano,
            MONTH(`data`) AS mes,
            SUM(tempo) AS tempo_extra
    FROM
        rh.aprovacoes
    WHERE
        (tipo = 'BH' OR tipo = 'HE')
            AND estado = 1
            AND YEAR(aprovacoes.`data`) = 2016
    GROUP BY MONTH(`data`)) AS t1
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        MONTH(`data`) AS mes, SUM(ativo) AS tempo_ativo
    FROM
        rh.processamento
    GROUP BY MONTH(`data`)) AS t2 ON t1.mes = t2.mes
ORDER BY mes DESC;
```

How can i make months start on 23rd of the last month and end on 22nd of the current month.

For example, April starting on March 23rd and end on April 22nd.

Comment: You can always play with the parameter passed in MONTH() function like you can use DATEADD Functions in SQL to either add days or subtract days from the date you are passing. And according to the date, month will be returned. Not sure of MySql though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply subtract 22 days from your date and add a month:

```
(`data` - interval 22 day) + interval 1 month
```

- March 22 => February 28 or 29 => **March** 28 or 29
- March 23 => March 1 => **April** 1
- April 22 => March 31 => **April** 30
- April 23 => April 1 => **May** 1

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/54883

Your query joins records regardless of the year by the way. I don't think this is desired, so in below query I've corrected this.

```
SELECT t1.ano, t1.mes, tempo_extra, tempo_ativo, tempo_extra/tempo_ativo AS volume_extra
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    YEAR(data - interval 22 day + interval 1 month) AS ano,
    MONTH(data - interval 22 day + interval 1 month) AS mes, 
    SUM(tempo) AS tempo_extra
  FROM rh.aprovacoes
  WHERE (tipo = 'BH' OR tipo = 'HE') 
  AND estado = 1 
  AND YEAR(aprovacoes.data - interval 22 day + interval 1 month) = 2016
  GROUP BY 
    YEAR(data - interval 22 day + interval 1 month), 
    MONTH(data - interval 22 day + interval 1 month)
) AS t1
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
    YEAR(data - interval 22 day + interval 1 month) AS ano, 
    MONTH(data - interval 22 day + interval 1 month) AS mes, 
    SUM(ativo) AS tempo_ativo
  FROM rh.processamento
  GROUP BY 
    YEAR(data - interval 22 day + interval 1 month), 
    MONTH(data - interval 22 day + interval 1 month)
) AS t2 ON t1.ano = t2.ano AND t1.mes = t2.mes
ORDER BY t1.ano DESC, t1.mes DESC;
```

Comment: Lovely, but that `tipo` is crying out for an `IN ('BH','HE')`

Comment: @Arth: Yes, an IN clause would be my choice, too.

Comment: Thanks  @Thorsten Kettner.